# Problem with \setmathfont and siunitx

Tags: luatex, siunitx, unicode-math

I have some problem with the following code.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fontspec,luatextra,unicode-math}
\usepackage{icomma}
\usepackage[noload=abbr]{siunitx}
\sisetup{decimalsymbol=comma, detect-all}
\let\nbu\SI

\setmathfont[range={\mathscr,\mathbfscr},StylisticSet=0]{xits-math.otf}

\begin{document}
\nbu{7.8}{m} or $7,8 = \nbu{7.8}{m} = \mathscr{A}$ in math mode.\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't want `\itshape` for the `m`. With the following code, the result is good, but I don't want to put the `\setmathfont{}` inside the document environment (but in sty file). How is it possible ?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fontspec,luatextra,unicode-math}
\usepackage{icomma}
\usepackage[noload=abbr]{siunitx}
\sisetup{decimalsymbol=comma, detect-all}
\let\nbu\SI

\begin{document}
\setmathfont[range={\mathscr,\mathbfscr},StylisticSet=0]{xits-math.otf}
\nbu{7.8}{m} or $7,8 = \nbu{7.8}{m} = \mathscr{A}$ in math mode.\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks to all.

Comment: General information unrelated to your question: [Why should the `minimal` class be avoided?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided)

Comment: Ok. But same result with article.

Comment: Indeed; that is why I said it was unrelated. `:~)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that `siunitx` is missing some kind of "default" font for the cases except `\mathscr` and `\mathscrbf`:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fontspec,luatextra,unicode-math}
\usepackage[noload=abbr]{siunitx}
\sisetup{decimalsymbol=comma, detect-all,debug}
\let\nbu\SI

\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}
\setmathfont[range={\mathscr,\mathbfscr},StylisticSet=0]{xits-math.otf}

\begin{document}
\nbu{7.8}{m} or $7,8 = \nbu{7.8}{m} = \mathscr{A}$ in math mode.\par
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]